# File Association .tsv to excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Im sorry i know this question gets asked alot but i have tried many diffrent things and nothing seems to work. But i am trying to get .tsv files to open with Microsoft Excel.  I created a .tsv file on my desktop and at first it showed "test.tsv" with a blank icon.  I run the following commands.

assoc .tsv=tsvfile
ftype tsvfile="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\excel.exe" "%1"

Now the file has changed, but all that changed is it now shows "test" wnd when i try to open it it want me to choose a program.

I am curently on a windows 8.1 Pro machine if that makes any diffrence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel will not accept file-associations without a previous manipulation
of the registry:

- Start `regedit`
- Navigate to the key
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Spreadsheet\Microsoft Excel\Capabilities\FileAssociations`
- Right-click `FileAssociations` and select *New > String Value*
- Name it `.tsv`
- Double-click it and set its value to `Excel.SLK`

Alternatively, you may do the same with a `reg add` command:

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Spreadsheet\Microsoft Excel\Capabilities\FileAssociations" /v ".tsv" /t REG_SZ /d "Excel.SLK" /f
```

Now you may associate Excel to `.tsv` files by right-click of any such file
and *Open with > Choose another app*, or by using the *Default Programs* app.

If you are executing the commands in a batch file, remember to escape
the `%` character, like this:

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Spreadsheet\Microsoft Excel\Capabilities\FileAssociations" /v ".tsv" /t REG_SZ /d "Excel.SLK" /f
assoc .tsv=tsvfile
ftype tsvfile="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\excel.exe" "%%1"
```

Comment: i have been able to associate it before this with the open with.  But i need command line cause i got a machine that keeps changing the association back to notepad.  I want to make a script to run daily to ensure this never happens again.

Comment: I added the `reg` command for batch.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the current update.  Making a little bit of progress. Here is my current code.  The icon now changes to excel, but it only opens excel like a fresh worksheet.  Not the info that is in the file.

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Spreadsheet\Microsoft Excel\Capabilities\FileAssociations" /v ".tsv" /t REG_SZ /d "Excel.SLK" /f
assoc .tsv=tsvfile
ftype tsvfile="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\excel.exe" "%1"
```

Ok, i think i got the biggest part figured out now.  Now my only issue is when i run the above command as a .bat file.  that very last "%1" does not get added.  After the script runs all that is there is "". so for some reason it is dropping that last peramiter off. so just need to figure out a way to keep it there.

Comment: Solution in my answer.